# how to change the text added to the scene?

Tags: qt, qgraphicsscene

I want to add the text in my scene.and this text sometimes should be changed.how to change the text added to scene ? suppose i have a player that earned points and i put his points in my scene.when his points increase or decrease i have to change the text.how to do this work?

```
QString points;
QGraphicsTextItem* text;
QFont font;
font.setBold(true);
font.setPointSize(50);
font.setItalic(true);
te="Ponit";
text=scene->addText(points,font);
text->setPos(100,100);
text->setDefaultTextColor(QColor("red"));
```

Comment: You have `QGraphicsTextItem *text;` so you can just call `QGraphicsTextItem::setPlainText(const QString & text)` to change the text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you call [QGraphicsScene::addText](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qgraphicsscene.html#addText), it returns the [QGraphicsTextItem](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qgraphicstextitem.html). Using this object, you can set either [plain](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qgraphicstextitem.html#setPlainText) or [HTML](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qgraphicstextitem.html#setHtml) text. For example: -

```
text->setPlainText("Some New Text");
```